# Why does the host become unavailable?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, host

I have a simple code to send commands:

```
using ( Socket oSocket = new Socket ( AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp ) )
        {
            try
            {
                string sRet = String.Empty;
                oSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 500;
                oSocket.SendTimeout = 500;
                oSocket.Connect ( msHost, miPort );
                if ( oSocket.Connected )
                {
                    byte[] baSendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes ( sCommand + "\r" );
                    int iSend = oSocket.Send ( baSendBytes, 0, baSendBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None );
                    int iReceived = 0;
                    if ( iSend == baSendBytes.Length ) // if all sent
                        iReceived = oSocket.Receive ( abBuff, 0, abBuff.Length, SocketFlags.None );
                    if ( iReceived != 0 ) // if smth received
                    {
                        for ( int i = 0; i < iReceived; i++ )
                            sRet += Convert.ToChar ( abBuff [ i ] );
                        sRet = sRet.Trim ( );
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Send error";
                }
                return sRet;
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                //My log error here.
                return "Send error";
            }
```

Sometimes an error occurs here. The log says that the host was unavailable. This error appears at random time. Sometimes everything works well for five minutes. Sometimes one month. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the computer with which this problem occurs.
What do i need to check? Is there a serious flaw in this code?

Comment: *What do i need to check?* if host and client are connected to the network 24/7 (why you think that it's a problem with code not with a network?)

Comment: Yes it is possible. But I still can’t access the necessary computer and network to verify this. Therefore, I want to check in advance everything I can. Maybe create another log that will allow you to identify a problem in the code, if any...